# Reading file to array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am reading and counting the number of lines in a file, then initializing an array with the same number of spaces as the number of lines. The file is then read again and each line is assigned to that position of the array. For example, the first line would be stored in the index position of 0. I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace testProg
{
    class program
    {
        static void main(){
        Console.WriteLine("enter your filename for reading!");

        fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        using (StreamReader rs = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line2;
            while ((line2 = rs.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                arraysize = arraysize+1;//this goes through and gets the number of lines
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(arraysize);
        string[] unenc = new string[arraysize]; //this creates the array dynamically
        int i = -1;//starts at position -1 then +1 so starts at 0
        using (StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string linefinal;
            while ((linefinal = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(linefinal);//this will write the current line
                unenc[i + 1] = linefinal;// this should store the string above in the current position

                Console.WriteLine(unenc[i]);//this should output the same line it does not the index is just empty ? but it should be stored yet it is not     

            }
        }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why not use `List<string>`, or `File.ReadAllLines` or for lazy evaluation `File.ReadLines` ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What @Habib said.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use preexisting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not saving the incremented value of `i` anywhere.

You could modify you code like so:

```
while ((linefinal = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(linefinal);

    unenc[i + 1] = linefinal;

    Console.WriteLine(unenc[i]);

    i++;
}
```

---

So your query in comments is

> would the array not update the value of i in the section where `unenc[i+1]`?

What `i + 1` does is return the value of "`i` plus `1`".

If you want to increment the value, you have two options:

**Increment after returning value**:

```
var oldValue = i++;
var newValue = i;
```

**Increment before returning value**:

```
var oldValue = i;
var newValue = ++i;
```

---

#### Code optimisation

You're having to read your file twice in order to get the number of lines so you can find out how big your array is. .NET provides a lovely class which will help you in this instance: `List<>`.

`List<int>` is a wrapper for `int[]` which manages the length of its internal array on the fly, which means while with an array you have to do this:

```
var array = int[3];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[3] = 3:
```

with a `List<int>` you can simply do the following

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
```

With an array you'd have to copy to a larger array if you wanted to add another element, with list, this is all done for you internally.

Of course you can still access a list by `var item = list[3];`.

So utilising this, you can do away with the first read of the file and just keep adding to a list.

Comment: @dav_i would the array not update the value of i in the section where unenc[i+1]?

Comment: A little mistake: "Increment before returning value" would be ++i.

Comment: @elgonzo Sorry! Mistyped! Obviously what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, consider using a List object. You can use the Add() method to continuously add items as you read them. Once complete, you can simply call the ToArray() method on the List object to get the array you need. You'll have all of the index values matching each line.

Comment: +1 for addressing the underlying issue rather than the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
unenc[i + 1] = linefinal;
```

isn't quite right. I belive you mean

```
unenc[i++] = linefinal;
```

Your line does not change the value of `i` as it goes through the loop.

Comment: Probably wants `++i` since i is initialized with -1.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use `ArrayList`. Please see the below code snippet

```
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
using (StreamReader rs = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\vimal\Desktop\test.txt"))
{
     string line = null;
     while ((line = rs.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
        lines.Add(line);
     }
}
```